# Unintended Behavior of Vertex Color

Tags: javascript, graphics, webgl

I'm trying to create a vertex color change feature using `varying` which is intended to give a result of gradient appearance of each vertex like this

[image]

Meanwhile after inserting such a color combination like this

```js
...
    this.vertices[0].setColor([255,0,0,1]); // red
    this.vertices[1].setColor([255,0,0,1]); // red
    this.vertices[2].setColor([255,0,0,1]); // red
    this.vertices[3].setColor([255,255,0,1]);  // yellow
...
```

The result is like this

[image]

It is supposed to be intended as a yellow gradient only on bottom left side of the shape, but instead, a half triangle was created.

Here is my shader C source code

```js
const vSource = `
    attribute vec4 vPosition;
    attribute vec4 vColor;
    varying vec4 fColor;
    void main() {
        gl_Position = vPosition;
        fColor = vColor;
    }
`;

const fSource = `
    precision mediump float;
    varying vec4 fColor;
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = fColor;
    }
`;
```

And here is the implementation of render function

```js
  render = (gl, program, vBuffer, cBuffer) => {
    const vertices = [];
    const colors = [];

    for (let j = 0; j < this.vertices.length; j++) {
      vertices.push(this.vertices[j].coordinate);
      colors.push(this.vertices[j].color);
    }

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    const vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition,2,gl.FLOAT,false,0,0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    const vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor,4,gl.FLOAT,false,0,0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

    if (this.shape == "line") {
      gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, vertices.length);
    } else {
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertices.length); // in this case, it is going to be TRIANGLE_FAN primitive
    }
  };
```

Would be thankful if you guys can catch something odd that might result in the bug.

P.S.: I have implemented shape creation such as polygon, transformation, and such, the coordinate-related action seems perfect, I just couldn't comprehend the problem that caused the vertices color to be like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of the color channels are floating point numbers in range [0.0, 1.0], but not integral numbers in range [0, 255]. e.g.:

```js
this.vertices[0].setColor([1,0,0,1]); // red
this.vertices[1].setColor([0,1,0,1]); // green
this.vertices[2].setColor([1,0,1,1]); // blue
this.vertices[3].setColor([1,1,0,1]); // yellow
```